# Library to resize image in .net

Tags: .net, image, resize

Is there a good library to resize an image in .NET with good quality? I'm not pleased with the quality of resized images that GDI+ produces.

It does not matter if the library is free or at a cost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using the [imageresizer](/questions/tagged/imageresizer) library by Imazen / Nathanael Jones ([website](http://imageresizing.net)), which works great.

Comment: New website link: http://imageresizing.net/  Oh, and there are now plugins you can add to get abilities like seam carving, Amazon CloudFront caching, disk caching, Amazon S3 reading, etc...

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty odd, GDI+ has nice filters.  Be sure to set the Graphics.InterpolationMode property to a high quality setting.  LeadTools is one of the leading graphics libraries, ImageMagick if you prefer open source.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... try this:

http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/C-Sharp/Lossless-Image-Resizing-in-C-Sharp/2/

It's talking about an image quantization library that (if you look through the other pages of the tutorial) apparently will provide a much higher quality image output.